# IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections

I would like to ask some of you smart guys :) if it is possible to have directory structure in IBM Connections files. There is also library but i can't map it via webdav/smdb maybe it is about my information gap, but what I can is install desktop plugin ( only MS win) and then map my structure. But only files, no communities. And within files there cant be create directory in directory structure ( may i be wrong but i tried much and nothing changed my mind ). So if someone has ever experienced this before.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not as obvious as a File Repository like you experience in Windows Explorer. IBM Connections does enable you to use files / folders

You can find more information about the folders API at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_folders_ic45&content=pdcontent

However, since you mentioned webdav, you may want to look at using CMIS and Apache Chemistry to access the CMIS APIs.  That should give you the most flexibility in mapping your WebDav to Connections
http://chemistry.apache.org/

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=How_to_Use_Files_CMIS_APIs_with_Media_Gallery_ic45&content=pdcontent

An example of what you can do with CMIS is http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/Demo_Using_CMIS_Connectors_with_Lotus_Connections_Files

Comment: Hello. This was useful in many ways. But there isnt that explained if its possible to create folder inside of folder. And if it is then how. :(((

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to create subfolders, if it is you can do it via CMIS.

Answer (score 1):

The Files application does not support sub folders.  Sub folders are available with IBM Connections Content Manager (CCM). CCM is an additional license but supports workflow and check in check out features as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matt M answer.

CCM use FileNet P8 repository to persist the files, in this case you can start to use IBM Content Navigator client with Desktop Sync options, may be it will be usefull for your requirements.